# How to modify boost polygon?

Tags: c++, boost, geometry, boost-geometry

I really need to access separate points of the boost polygon, so I can add/remove/move them.

I found that `polygon` has outer and inner rings and I can iterate them somewhat like this

```
auto& polygon = experiment->mPolygons.at(experiment->selectedPolygonIndex);
auto& outerRing = boost::geometry::exterior_ring(polygon);

for(auto& point : outerRing)
{
    //some stuff using point
}
```

But it does'nt help with modifications. I alose would like to know point's index, so I could insert a new one in the right position.

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you clarify which library you need/intend to use? Your question speaks of Boost Polygon, but the code (to me) looks like Boost Geometry. Are you mixing libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you actually meant Boost Geometry (the library), you can find the description of the Polygon Concept here: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/concepts/concept_polygon.html

Note that it confirms that the polygon template models that concept.

You'll also note that many of the operations possible aren't directly included on that page. Instead you'll have to click through to the [Ring concept](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/concepts/concept_ring.html) that describes the constituent elements.

The concepts are geared to creating read-only views of arbitrary (user-supplied) data-structures. However, some operations are included as *algorithms*, like: [bg::assign](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/assign.html) (which has assign_values, assign_zero, assign_points, assign_inverse among others), [bg::append](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/append.html) etc.